# How to add a shell script as a command offered by a Snap?

Tags: scripts, snap, packaging

Say I have a basic shell script foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]
do
    echo "looping"
    sleep 1
done
```

And I want to have this offered up as a command: `/snap/bin/myapp.foo`

I have the snapcraft.yaml:

```
apps:                                                                                                                                              
  foo:
    command: opt/foo/bin/foo.sh

parts:
  foo:
    source: .
    plugin: dump
    organize:
      foo.sh: opt/foo/bin/foo.sh
```

This results in a file `/snap/bin/myapp.foo` but it's a link to /usr/bin/snap.  I get a segmentation fault when running the command.

What is the correct way to setup snapcraft.yaml for this?  I'm wondering if I have to package `sh` into the Snap?  Or if shell scripts are not meant to be used in snaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so two things were missing.

1) Under the command section the $SNAP environment variable should be used.  All the parts that you create will be stored relative to that env variable at runtime.

2) Rather than invoking the shell script directly, specify the interpreter (in this case "sh").  It failed without that.

```
apps:
  foo:
    command: sh $SNAP/opt/foo/bin/foo.sh

parts:
  foo:
    source: .
    plugin: dump
    organize:
            foo.sh: opt/foo/bin/foo.sh
```

ADDENDUM 1: It turns out the really important factor for my use was that in Ubuntu 18, Snap is tied to the version of libc that is in Ubuntu 16.  This causes Snap to need to suck up Ubuntu 18's libc6 into my Snap, which in turn creates conflicts with things like bash and dash/sh.

If you are attempting to run shell scripts and are seeing segfaults, it's likely related to this.  A process tries to invoke the shell script, reads the "shebang" at the top ("#!/bin/bash") and when it runs /bin/bash it gets a libc conflict.

ADDENDUM 2: For situations where a parent process launches shell scripts, be careful that the "shebang" statement at the top will likely be invalid.  For example "#!/bin/sh" will not resolve correctly because the actual path would be "$SNAP/bin/sh", which would resolve to something like "/snap/project-name/project-revision/bin/sh".

To get around this, make sure the PATH environment is getting passed to the program with $SNAP prefixed to every relevant path.  Then adjust the parent program to invoke the script with the interpreter, for example "bash child.sh" vs. "child.sh".